# SQL LAG() function returning 0 for every row despite available previous rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I'm using the LAG() function in SQL to calculate the difference between the current month's tips sum and the previous month's tips sum for each taxi driver. However, the LAG() function is returning 0 for every row, even though there should be previous rows to reference.

This is the example of the query I am using now:

```sql
    SELECT 
    td.taxi_id,
    td.year,
    td.month,
    td.tips_sum,
    (td.tips_sum - 
    LAG(td.tips_sum, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY td.taxi_id ORDER BY td.year, td.month) /
    NULLIF(LAG(td.tips_sum, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY td.taxi_id ORDER BY td.year, td.month), 0) AS tips_change
FROM 
    tips_data td
ORDER BY 
    td.tips_sum DESC
LIMIT 3
```

[Example of the result I get right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpMkl.png)

Comment: If the ``Texi_id`` is always unique then you should not use partition by on it.

Comment: Perhaps you need `OVER (ORDER BY td.year, td.month, td.taxi_id)` or `OVER (ORDER BY td.year, td.month, td.tips_sum DESC)`

Comment: @sa-es-ir taxi_id is unique, but the idea is to compare how the total sum changed for each taxi_id, so for each taxi_id there will be several months to compare with each other. Should I still not use partition by taxi_id?

Comment: Hi - please update your question with enough sample data to illustrate the possible use cases and show the result you want to achieve based on that sample data. Ensure this is all editable text, appropriately formatted and please don’t link to external images